# List or Filter EC2 instances based on specific tag

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

Anyone have idea how to filter the AWS EC2 instances based on specific tag using PowerShell?

I have used:

`$instance = Get-EC2Instance -Filter @( @{name='tag:<name>'; values="<IIS>"}; @{name='instance-state-code'; values = 16} ) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty instances`

Also tried:

```
"require 'aws-sdk-ec2'  
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new(region: 'us-east-1') ec2.instances({filters: [{name: 'tag:<name>', values: ['<IIS>']}]})"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right way, look at this [link](https://overpoweredshell.com/AWS-PowerShell-EC2-Tags-and-Filtering/#searching-for-tags).

```
$searchFor =@(
    @{
        name = 'tag:Environment'
        values = "Dev"
    }
)
Get-EC2Instance -Filter $searchFor
```

Advanced search function, found on the website:

```
Function ConvertTo-EC2Filter
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            ValueFromPipeline,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [HashTable]
        $Filter
    )
    Begin
    {
        $ec2Filter = @()    
    }
    Process
    {

        $ec2Filter = Foreach ($key in $Filter.Keys)
        {
            @{
                name   = $key
                values = $Filter[$key]
            }
        }
    }
    End
    {
        $ec2Filter
    }
}
```